# Validation in Numeric Column or Validation Setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, validation

I am trying to set a validation setting to display an error message. I have a column **Type** set to choice (Radio buttons) with two options (No Time and Minutes), I have a further column **MinutesSet** set to number.

What I need is that if **Minutes** is selected from the **Type** choice the column **MinutesSet** must contain a number.

I would also like that if **No Time** is selected from the **Type** choice and the user enters a number in the **MinutesSet** column it will display error.

What would the formula be and should I just use the Validation in the Minutes column as this is available or should I use the Validation option in the generic settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample formula you can use via *List settings* > *Validation settings*:

```
=IF([Type]="Minutes",NOT(ISBLANK([MinutesSet])),TRUE)
=IF([Type]="No Time",ISBLANK([MinutesSet]),TRUE)
```

Reference: [IS functions.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the following Form Validation to your list:

```
=IF(OR(AND(DataType="Minutes",MinuteSet>-1),AND(DataType="No Time",MinuteSet="")),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Note: Replace column names and values as per your list

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solved my query!